# Oracle MAF feature Constraints are not working with multiple constraint with same property

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I am using multiple `<adfmf:constraint >`  with same property property="user.roles" but, the fature is not rendering if that user has any one role. If I am using only one `<adfmf:constraint >` it is working.

For reference, please see below code

```
 <adfmf:constraints>
            <adfmf:constraint operator="contains" value="role1" id="c10" property="user.roles"/>
 <adfmf:constraint operator="contains" value="role2" id="c10" property="user.roles"/>
        </adfmf:constraints>
```

If user has role1 only one role feature is not showing if we remove role2 it is showing.

Please suggest.